# Centos 7, Kickstart , Error setting up base repository during installation

Tags: centos7, kickstart

I  am trying to install centos 7 using kickstart on vmware 12.
I have downloaded iso and installed many virtual machines using the same iso package.

**I am getting error: Error setting up base repository**

Steps I am performing for kickstart.
mount /dev/sr0 /webdir/rhel //CD rom iso is mounted here
chown -R root:root /website/rhel 
chmod 755 /webdir/ks.cfg

My kick start file

```
#version=RHEL7
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512

# Use CDROM installation media
#cdrom
url --url http://192.168.1.201/rhel
# Use graphical install
graphical
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Network information
network  --bootproto=static --device=eno16777736 

--gateway=192.168.1.1 --ip=192.168.1.200 --

nameserver=192.168.1.1 --netmask=255.255.255.0 

--noipv6 --activate
#network  --hostname=server.homedomain.com
# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $6$ozwaEbpRPt30cDvE

$AvQIjqHZAkFSCqc8vfO.Kta6QPw7AXTNFXtNASV2HGU9pnc

lcNcpzjvoe4wFc9bdoo8Kyfe01tuauM0k9s3pn/
# System timezone
timezone Asia/Karachi --isUtc --nontp
user --name=atif --password=asif10
#user --name=asif --password=

$6$DThpCq/Gemo2s3DL

$3y4CtyJYO.gvZ67acOskcOvKNUJiYlz3hEUF/LoRu0FDDIc

u6rVS5OFVfLygbDjLOjkANvs5aCupKawyRw3jU1 --

iscrypted --gecos="Muhammad Asif"
# X Window System configuration information
xconfig  --startxonboot
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel
# Disk partitioning information
part pv.196 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=sda --

size=16900
part /boot --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --

size=1024 --label=boot
volgroup centos --pesize=4096 pv.196
logvol /home  --fstype="xfs" --size=1024 --

label="home" --name=home --vgname=centos
logvol swap  --fstype="swap" --size=1024 --

name=swap --vgname=centos
logvol /  --fstype="xfs" --size=14848 --

label="root" --name=root --vgname=centos

%packages
@base
@core
@desktop-debugging
@dial-up
@directory-client
@fonts
@gnome-desktop
@guest-agents
@guest-desktop-agents
@input-methods
@internet-browser
@java-platform
@multimedia
@network-file-system-client
@networkmanager-submodules
@print-client
@x11

%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --disable --reserve-

mb='auto'

%end
```

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: are folding in original file, or just a typo from copy/paste (network line, password line) ?

Comment: this is the orignal anaconda-ks.cfg file copied from /root/ , just added url line to make it work over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been searching for this solution whole day, After quite a lot of googling . It has worked .

**I have changed only one line in ks.cfg**

**

```
# Use CDROM installation media
#cdrom
url --url="http://192.168.1.215/rhel"  // only added = and "" only 
# Use graphical install
graphical
```

**

**Repeat of steps again for others:**

Server Setup: 
using http

webdir= /var/www/html

```
mkdir /webdir/rhel <br>
mount /dev/sr0 /webdir/rhel    //CDROM iso is mounted here <br>
chown -R root:root /website/rhel <br>
chmod 755 /webdir/ks.cfg<br>
```

Client:

Press Esc: 
boot: linux ks=http://192.168.1.215/ks.cfg

It worked perfect.

Comment: .....well done!

Comment: Will this still work if your server hosting the ISO images is behind a proxy but your client is on the same network? I have a similar set up but my installation keeps failing because of "Installation source not found"

Answer (score 1):

you set up defines a CD install, but your kick script defines a network location.

Steps I am performing for kickstart.
mount /dev/sr0 /webdir/rhel //CD rom iso is mounted here
chown -R root:root /website/rhel 
chmod 755 /webdir/ks.cfg

```
# Use CDROM installation media
#cdrom
url --url http://192.168.1.201/rhel
```

shouldn't it be something like:

```
# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
repo --name="RHEL7" --baseurl=cdrom:sr0
```

Comment: I want to peform network installation. once the ks.cfg file is downloaded on the client , it will search for dvd content on the mentioned path ................ url --url http://192.168.1.201/rhel  ............... I dont want to install it from the local cd rom

Comment: it that case I would look at your apache config, is directory listing enabled - can you view it from a browser? - it would also need to be PXE image and not an ISO

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ap-install-server.html

Comment: apache is working fine. as i am able to download ks.cfg onto the client. the only error was related to installation source..